# WP Проблема вывода произвольного списка комментариев wp_list_comments();

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на `WordPress` где на произвольном типе записей необходимо выводить список комментариев, кастомного типа.(Что б список по умолчанию, который применяеться к постам не исправлялся) Делаю, при помощи функции `wp_list_comments()` как описано [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_comments).

1. В нужном месте своего файла `single-companies.php` вызываю этот список из кастомного файла

```
<?php if (comments_open() || get_comments_number()) :
    comments_template('template-parts/custom-comments-template');
endif; ?>
```

2. В файле `custom-comments-template.php` инициализирую эти отзывы

```
<?php if (post_password_required()) {
    return;
}

//'type=comment&callback=reviews_theme_comment'
?>
    <div id="comments" class="company-rewiew-list">
        <?php wp_list_comments(array(
            'type' => 'comment',
            'callback' => 'reviews_theme_comment',
        )); ?>
    </div>
<?php
function reviews_theme_comment($comment, $args, $depth)
{
    if ('div' === $args['style']) {
        $tag = 'div';
        $add_below = 'comment';
    } else {
        $tag = 'li';
        $add_below = 'div-comment';
    }

    $classes = ' ' . comment_class(empty($args['has_children']) ? '' : 'parent', null, null, false);
    ?>

    <<?php echo $tag, $classes; ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
    <?php if ('div' != $args['style']) { ?>
    <ul id="div-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>" class="comment-body"><?php
} ?>
    <li class="rewiew-card-item">
        <h1>It's TEST COMMENT</h1>
        <div class="comment-author vcard">
            <?php
            if ($args['avatar_size'] != 0) {
                echo get_avatar($comment, $args['avatar_size']);
            }
            printf(
                __('<cite class="fn">%s</cite> <span class="says">says:</span>'),
                get_comment_author_link()
            );
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') { ?>
            <em class="comment-awaiting-moderation">
                <?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.'); ?>
            </em><br/>
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
            <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(get_comment_link($comment->comment_ID)); ?>">
                <?php
            printf(
                __( '%1$s at %2$s' ),
                get_comment_date(),
                get_comment_time()
            ); ?>
            </a>

            <?php edit_comment_link(__('(Edit)'), '  ', ''); ?>
        </div>

        <?php comment_text(); ?>

        <div class="reply">
            <?php
            comment_reply_link(
                array_merge(
                    $args,
                    array(
                        'add_below' => $add_below,
                        'depth' => $depth,
                        'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']
                    )
                )
            ); ?>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php if ('div' != $args['style']) { ?>
    </ul>
<?php }
}
```

И тут меня ждет облом. Мне на страницу выводиться дефолтный список отзывов, а не тот, что я тут вызываю. Оно вроде как вообще не задействует `'callback' => 'reviews_theme_comment',` функцию. Пробовал и переносить данную функцию и в файл - `functions.php` и на кешсбрасывал. Результата ноль, оно выводит но не в том формате. Подскажите, пожалуйста в чём ошибка ?

Comment: Функция [comments_template()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/#parameters) принимает в качестве первого параметра путь к файлу с расширением и должен быть еще слеш перед `template-parts`, Ваше подключение должно выглядеть таким образом: `comments_template('/template-parts/custom-comments-template.php');`