# WP Как добавлять кастомные поля в комментарии?

Tags: wordpress

Пробую разобраться в примере приведенном на [вот этой странице](https://wp-kama.ru/id_8342/kak-dobavit-proizvolnye-polya-v-formu-kommentariev-wordpress.html).

Есть дочерняя тема. В ней создаю файл `single-companies.php`
В котором подключаю приведенный пример.

`<?php get_template_part('template-parts/test'); ?>`

Файл `test.php` выглядит так

```
<?php

// Добавляем поля для всех пользователей
add_action( 'comment_form_logged_in_after', 'extend_comment_custom_fields' );
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'extend_comment_custom_fields' );
function extend_comment_custom_fields() {

    echo '<p class="comment-form-title">'.
        '<label for="title">' . __( 'Comment Title' ) . '</label>'.
        '<input id="title" name="title" type="text" size="30"/></p>';

    echo '<p class="comment-form-rating">'.
        '<label for="rating">'. __('Rating') . '<span class="required">*</span></label>
              <span class="commentratingbox">';

    for( $i=1; $i <= 5; $i++ ){
        echo '
        <label class="commentrating" style="display:inline-block;">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="'. $i .'"/> '. $i .'
        </label>';
    }

    echo'</span></p>';
}

// Проверяем, заполнено ли поле "Рейтинг"
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'verify_extend_comment_meta_data' );
function verify_extend_comment_meta_data( $commentdata ) {

    // ничего не делаем если это ответ на комментарий
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && $_REQUEST['action'] === 'replyto-comment' ) {
        return $commentdata;
    }

    if ( empty( $_POST['rating'] ) || ! (int)$_POST['rating'] ) {
        wp_die( __( 'Error: You did not add a rating. Hit the Back button on your Web browser and resubmit your comment with a rating.' ) );
    }

    return $commentdata;
}

add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_extend_comment_meta_data' );
function save_extend_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ){

    if( !empty( $_POST['phone'] ) ){
        $phone = sanitize_text_field($_POST['phone']);
        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'phone', $phone );
    }

    if( !empty( $_POST['title'] ) ){
        $title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['title']);
        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'title', $title );
    }

    if( !empty( $_POST['rating'] ) ){
        $rating = intval($_POST['rating']);
        add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'rating', $rating );
    }

}
```

Оно замечательно отображает, делает проверку, но в базу данных `commentmeta` ничего не пишет из кастомных полей (Тоесть только базовый комментарий сохраняет). В чём может быть проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста ?

Comment: При добавлении в дефолтную тему данного кастомного вывода результат тот же.

Comment: Может ли это быть связано, что был розширен функционал do_action( 'comment_post', $comment_id, $commentdata['comment_approved'], $commentdata );  ??? Оно же должно принимать $comment_id по умолчанию ?

Answer (score 0):

Если кто-то будет искать решени. Код правильный - секрет того почему оно не работало, и не сохраняло в базу данных - связано с тем, что функцию сохранения необходимо вызывать из `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_extend_comment_meta_data' );
function save_extend_comment_meta_data( $comment_id ){ ... }
```

Comment: Так это и не должно было быть темплейт партом.

Comment: Я этого не знал, в примерах которые приводяться на форумах всё засовывают либо в плагин, либо куда-то. У меня задача выводить отдельно, кастомного вида, блок описания комментария и отдельно список, тоже кастомного вида с комментариями. При этом есть тип записи - посты, где выводится стандартное поле, и они не должны конфликтовать.

Comment: В темплейтах и темплейт партах обычно не пишут таких вещей, там не должно быть бизнес-логики

Comment: @Simon можешь, подсказать, а что не так в выводи списка этих комментариев ? Вот этот вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1542480/wp-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b2-wp-list-comments